# Click on a link takes me to a webpage but I cannot use its URL to go directly to that webpage

Tags: url, redirect

I'm trying to go directly to the calottery detailed draw results webpage based on the draw date and draw number, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how to do it.

For example, if I go to this link http://www.calottery.ca.gov/play/draw-games/fantasy-5/winning-numbers and click on the hyperlink Draw **Feb 26, 2016 - 8147**, it will take me to its detailed draw result page. The web browser URL will show `http://www.calottery.ca.gov/play/draw-games/fantasy-5/winning-numbers/?DrawDate=Feb%2026,%202016&DrawNumber=8147`
[image]

[image]

However, when I try to copy and paste this link to my web browser address bar and try to go there directly, it doesn't give me the same page. It will redirect me back to the http://www.calottery.ca.gov/play/draw-games/fantasy-5/winning-numbers page instead.

I have tried looking at the page source in Google Chrome and for a given draw hyperlink its link is the same to what I use to paste into my address bar. Below is an example of the page source for a draw:

```
<table class='tag_even numbers' width='100%' border='0'><thead><tr><th>Draw</th><th>Winning Numbers</th><th>&nbsp;</th></tr></thead>         
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="/play/draw-games/fantasy-5/winning-numbers/?DrawDate=Feb 26, 2016&DrawNumber=8147">
                    <span id="objBody_content_0_pagecontent_0_objPastWinningNumbers_rptPast_ctl01_lblDrawDateNumber" title="8147">Feb 26, 2016 - 8147</span>
                </a>
            </td>                               
        </tr>
```

Can someone tell me what it's doing or how I can get to a specific detailed draw results based on the draw date and draw number?

Thank you in advance.